# open MP setup in Xcode

Tags: openmp

I am setting up open MP in the Xcode. In the build phase I have to add file libomp.dylib, but when I searching in the finder it shows nothing.

I have tried the command 'brew install libomp' also but couldn't find the file.
please help me out.

Answer (score 0):

It is tricky, you can find more information here:
https://mac.r-project.org/openmp/